# Скрывать блок при клике вне него

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть кнопка, при клике на которую всплывает блок div

```
 function viewDiv(){
  document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
};
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при клике вне блока, от снова скрывался? И еще он почему-то появляется не по центру экрана, а где-то в углу, как это поправить?

Answer (score 1):

Суть в том чтобы проверить элемент на котором нажали, если он не внутри окна и не является самим окном, то спрятать окно.
Если нужна поддержка IE 11, то могу заменить, но будет больше кода.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button')
let element = document.querySelector('.div1')

// кнопка
btn.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  element.style.display = 'block'
})

// клик вне модалки и кнопки
document.addEventListener('click', outsideClickListener)

function outsideClickListener ({ target }) {
  if (!element.contains(target) && target !== btn)
    element.style.display = 'none'
}
```

```css
.div1 {
   background: yellow;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -50px;
   margin-top: -50px;
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Показать</button>
<div class="div1"></div>
```